# Pass NSArray as parameter in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

How to pass `NSArray` as a parameter in `AFNetworking`?

The `API` that I am trying to call is expecting a **list(array)**.
I cannot use **dictionary** because there is no key.

Comment: And what's your issue? Can't you pass a `NSArray` in the parameters?

Comment: No i am not able to pass NSArray, could please tell me the syntax??

Comment: Could you provide some code? For instance, what version of AFNetworking are you using?

Comment: - (void)addVideo:(NSDictionary *)selectedVideoDictionary  completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *json, BOOL success))completion

Comment: I tried passing NSArray instead of NSDictionary but it's not accepting

Comment: Please, edit your question with your code (that way it's clearer and can be formatted), and what's that method? Is it really from AFNetworking?

Comment: - (void)addVideo:(NSArray *)selectedVideoDictionary completion:(void (^)(NSDictionary *json, BOOL success))completion

I changed the syntax and it's working now.
thanks for your help

Comment: Could you explain why the marked question solves your issue? Because the code is in fact quite "generic".

Comment: Marked answer shows the correct syntax of, how to pass an array using AFNetworking

Comment: That what I said at the beginning, but it seems that your real issue what about `addVideo:completion:` rather than AFNetworking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;

 manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
 manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:500.0];
[manager POST:strRequestUrl parameters:yourArray success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{

     NSString *msg;
     NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:responseObject
                                                               options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                                 error:nil];
     NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

// instead of array u can send JSON string as input parameter

```
NSMutableDictionary *dicinput = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:arrayToConvert]) {
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arrayToConvert
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
   NSString *JSONString;
   if (!jsonData) {
       NSLog(@"JSON error:%@", error);
   } else {

       JSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       [dicinput setValue:JSONString forkey:@"input"];
  }

}
```

Comment: Why are you putting the JSON string into a dictionary?

Comment: if he have more than one one parameters(array and other parametrs), he can prepare url by using dictionary keys easily

Comment: in the above discussion of his comments his method takes dictionary as Parameter